# Google spreadhseet EVAL function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet with different sheets, each one representing a different week.

For example:

- 1/12 - 1/16
- 1/19 - 1/23

I want to do a chart based on the content of those sheets. Is there any way I can make a formula and extract the name of the sheet from a content of a cell?

For example something like "=EVAL(A1)!$B$4", then I would have the content from "1/12 - 1/16"!$B$4 instead of having to go through each one of the weeks of the year manually.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: For people looking at this question for more generic eval function, I used this. https://support.google.com/docs/thread/13826624/evaluate-string-as-formula?hl=en
Citing: "look into Google Apps Script to make that work.

As a very simple example, this custom function works for simple math:
`function run(input){
  return eval(input);
}`

It works properly for your example. So if A1 = "2+2" then you could write =RUN(A1) in B1 and it would return 4."

Answer (score 10):

There’s no need to use AppScript, `INDIRECT` is enough to read a sheet name from a cell:

```
=INDIRECT(A1 & "!$B$4")
```

However, it looks like Andy’s answer is the way to go if you want to get the sheet name from its index rather than from a cell.

Answer (score 3):

It'd be best to use AppScript. In Tools -> Script Editor make a new AppScript script:

```
function getSheetName(i) {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets() 
  return s[i].getName();
}
```

With that in your script, you can then use the custom function `=getSheetName(<SHEETNUMBER>)` and it will retrieve the sheet name based what sheet number it is (starting from 0). From there, just incorporate it into your formulas. You may need to use [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en).

Example: `=INDIRECT(getSheetName(1)&"!A1")` to get cell A1 in the second sheet.